# Calling Partial View Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view defined like this in my `/Shared` folder

```html
<div id="myProducts">
  @Html.Partial("_ProductsList",Model)
 </div>
```

I want to load `_ProductsList` through JQuery. Basically, I am trying to refresh my `_ProductsList` view on button click. I tried to do like this:

```
$('myProducts').Load(/Shared/_ProductsList)
```

But I get a "resource not found error".

Comment: [A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838082/asp-net-core-strategy-for-returning-partial-views-via-ajax-requests) is asking something different, [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65839922/3025856) to the question demonstrate how to load a partial via AJAX. (Disclaimer: I posted an answer to that question myself—though my answer doesn't actually address your question; the others might.)

Comment: Aside, `/Shared/_ProductsList` should be in quotes within your jQuery. I assume that's a typo. Also, can you confirm that you're able to navigate to `/Shared/_ProductsList` and get a response back? That will help confirm that this isn't a routing issue.

Comment: You need to create a method in the controller which returns the `/Shared/_ProductsList` partial view. You can call this method from the jquery as you do with other views

Answer (score 2):

try to use this ajax code

```
        $.ajax({
        
            url: "/MyController/MyAction",
            type: "POST", //or "GET" if you don't send body data
            success: function (result) {
                    $("#myProducts").html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, exception) {
               
            }
        });
```

and the action

```
public partial class MyController : Controller
{
  public IActionResult MyAction()
  {
      var model=new myModel { ... assign model properties  };
     return PartialView("_ProductsList", model);
 }
}
```